# dependent variable on logarithmic scale, can treat as linear?

Tags: mixed-model

I have a dependent variable on a logarithmic scale, specifically, it is loudness measured in dB. I am using a mixed effects model since I have a longitudinal data structure. Is a linear mixed effects model appropriate, i.e., can I treat the dependent variable as continuous?

Comment: Having a continuous response and a linear model are quite different questions.

Comment: More of an opinion. Working in epidemiology, I have sat in seminars and read papers on occupational health focusing on noise. Fitting noise level measured in dB as is into a linear regression model is very unlikely to surprise anyone in this field. As long as you have checked the assumptions during the modeling building, it should be fine. Yet, you can always categorize it into high/low noise if that truly bothers you.

Answer (score 3):

The assumptions behind a linear mixed model are for the error terms, not directly about the response outcome variable. Hence, you will need to check the assumptions for the error terms using the residuals of the model you will fit. If the assumptions do not seem to be seriously violated, you could use the model.